# Convert directory of Images to video (using ffmpeg-fluent)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am creating a Node.js application with the `ffmpeg-fluent` library but I'm having trouble with trying to convert a directory full of images into a video such that each image is one frame of the video. The code here is only showing one frame.

```js
    fs.readdir(full_path_to_cache, (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        var command = ffmpeg()
        files.forEach(file =>{
          command = command.input(path.join(full_path_to_cache,file))
        })

         command.fps(1)
                .output('output_video.mp4')
                .videoCodec('libx264')
                .on('end', () => {
                  console.log('Video creation completed.');
                })
                .on('error', err => {
                  console.error('Failed to create video:', err);
                })
                .run();

        
    });
```